Laptop keyboard randomly stops working on Debian 12
Recently, I've been facing with a really weird problem where the built-in keyboard on my laptop (Lenovo Yoga 300-11IBR) randomly stops working. Sometimes it stops working ten seconds after boot, sometimes it immediately stops working, and sometimes it doesn't stop working at all.
This is not an issue with my keyboard being faulty, as it works perfectly fine on Windows. External keyboards work normally.
In /var/log/kern.log I've only been able to find one message related to the keyboard, and it's repeated multiple times:
atkbd serio0: Failed to enable keyboard on iisa0060/serio0

I have tried setting different kernel parameters to no avail. All my drivers are up-to-date. I'm running Debian 12 bookworm.

Try kernel 6.9.6, if it doesn't work, file a bug report here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org

@ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks for the suggestion, I updated my kernel to 6.7.12 since this is the latest kernel I could install on Debian 12, and it now seems to work fine. :)
